# glTexSubImage2D is slow uploading YUV data

Tags: opengl, rendering, gpu, glteximage2d

I am writing a video player, I decoded the video frames and use 3 `sampler2D`s for receiving the YUV format frame data, it renders perfectly fine.

But it has serious performance issue with `glTexSubImage2D`. I observed strange behaviors:

1. Uploading YUV data in an order of Y, U, V, then uploading **U** is **randomly** slow(1ms to 100ms).
2. Uploading YUV data in an order of Y, V, U, then uploading **V** is **randomly** slow(1ms to 100ms).
3. Uploading YUV data in an order of U, V, Y, then uploading **Y** is **constantly** slow(10ms to 50ms).

For other components that are not slow to upload, they take less than 1ms. I use `glTexSubImage2D` with `internalFormat=GL_RED`, `format=GL_RED`, `dataType=GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

What could be the possible cause of these strange behaviors?

Comment: Those who suggests closing this question please leave your reason here, how is this question **OFF TOPIC**?

Comment: The problem with your question is that you're not asking in regards to a specific programming problem, but rather your question is too general. I mean, we have no way to understand why it is 'slow'. You haven't shown a single line of code.Neitgher we have any idea regarding your environment. What type of CPU/GPU. In short, you must provide detailed info ,including a source code, if you want us to try helping you.

Comment: I did provide all the information that I considered matter the most, the API I used, the execution time of the API, the way I called the API, the relevant parameters. Yes, I didn't mention the environment, sorry for that. But the environment is not special, and that's the reason why I didn't include it in the question. I run the code on MacOS(MacBook 2016) and an Android device with CPU `Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 821`, and GPU `Adreno™ 530`. They both yield the same result.

Comment: You must show actual code.   This is not enough info. Also how did you measure your timing?